# Cannot open react native drawer by swipe or hamburger

Tags: android, react-native

I'am playing around with React native but i can't get the Drawer to work.

I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShUYQz9uJ5g
Basically the navigation is working by using the navigation buttons, but i cannot open the drawer. Neither by swiping nor by touching the hamburger icon in the header.

I've read that i need to add this line to the top of my App.tsx, but this also doesn't help.

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

My code is the same as this official [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Tab%20navigation%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-pager-view%40*%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.7.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E3.0.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%406.3.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%406.4.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Felements%401.3.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%406.2.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%406.2.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%406.6.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%406.0.10%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%406.2.1&hideQueryParams=true&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F6.x%2Fdrawer-based-navigation.js)
The snack is working, but not on my physical android phone.

Does anyone else have the same problem?

Comment: Find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this same issue.

If by chance you do not need the swipe functionality you can set up you `Drawer.Navigator` like so with the `useLegacyImplementation` option

```
<Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" useLegacyImplementation>
```

This will make the hamburger button work.

I'm trying to figure out why the swiping won't work. I've tried implemented 'animated 2' but still no luck